# How to limit the touch area within single Imageview?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to limit the touch of Image-view according to it's height and width.

Comment: limit the touch? what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean while draging it will not go in second layout, it should be ends at the border of first layout

Comment: and you mean you want to limit your drag after calling `View#startDrag` / `View#startDragAndDrop` methods?

Comment: No not like that. If I'm draging from the first layout to second the app crashes. So I want to know how can i set the touch within a single layout so that it will not go in the second layout and crashes the app.

Comment: so HOW do you make a drag if not by calling `View#startDrag` / `View#startDragAndDrop` methods?

Comment: I'm using only OnTouchListener method to touch the image in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting empty views on the specific areas you want to set touch events for them.

for example: if you want to put 2 different touch events within single Imageview one for the right side and the other for the left side use this block of code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_side_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_side_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_view"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_side_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_side_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_view"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

then just set touch events to each View.